# How to connect hive to a Hadoop 2 based cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have setup one Hadoop2 based cluster with one namenode and two datanodes.
I have one edge node as well and there I want to setup Hive.
I want to configure/setup Hive in such a way that it runs its query related MapReduce jobs utilizing the cluster resources only.
By some googling ,it seems that for Hadoop1, setting the following property could have done the job (not sure though) .

`<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>hostname:portno</value>
  </property>`

But in case of Hadoop2 ,not sure what would be the correct property to change.
Could it be like the following ?

`<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>namenodehostname:50040</value>
  </property>`

Answer (score 1):

The Edge Node is just a interface to submit the Job either Map-reduce or Hive.
Edge Node has the similar conf file so that it can identify the Cluster as a whole.
So no such separate configuration is required from the edge node side.
When a job is submitted it'll always refer the core-site yarn-site hive-site file in main hadoop cluster and act accordingly.
However you can refer the following XML which needs to be configured on Hadoop Server Side[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhrT8.jpg)